# How to make a Many-To-One relationship in DataMapper

Tags: ruby, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I'm trying to create an association between two models:

```
class Person
   include DataMapper::Resource
   property :id, Serial
   property :name, String
end

class Country
   include DataMapper::Resource
   property :id, Serial
   property :name, String
end
```

I just need a simple relationship on Person (a `country_id`).

My first idea was to put a `has 1` property on Person:

```
class Person
   include DataMapper::Resource
   property :id, Serial
   property :name, String
   has 1, :country
end
```

Instead of a `country_id` on Person table, Datamapper created a `person_id` on Country.

To get what I need, I had to make it inverse:

```
class Country
   include DataMapper::Resource
   property :id, Serial
   property :name, String
   has 1, :person
end
```

This way I got my `country_id` field on Person table, but it really doesn't make any sense for me.

Am I misunderstanding something or is there another way to make this association?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This isn't a Sinatra question. Simply because a particular gem is part of your project isn't enough to tag it; It needs to be part of the code in question too. This is a Datamapper question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever Model A "has" Model B (either one or many), you add the foreign key to Model B.

The flipside of this is "belongs to" - that's what you put on the Model with the foreign key.

I guess in DataMapper you don't have to add foreign key columns explicitly, but you could still do it if you want.

```
# Person
property :country_id, Integer
```

Since the foreign key in on Person, you'd use "belongs to". It seems like the same thing as "has one", but it's not. You generally only need "has one" in special cases like one-to-one relationships.

```
# Person
belongs_to :country

# Country
has n, :people
# you could use has 1, :person if for some reason every country
# only had 1 person in it
```